# importing Data that is not ordered in a logical way

Tags: r, dataframe, import

I have data in the form of:

```
>sp|A6NMZ2|SNTAN_HUMAN Sentan OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SNTN PE=2 SV=1                 
39  S   AGC/PKA RKMPKRISISKQLAS 25.507  22.884
>sp|O00501|CLD5_HUMAN Claudin-5 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=CLDN5 PE=2 SV=1                  
201 S   AGC/PKA LSFPVKYSAPRRPTA 23.138  22.884
207 T   AGC/PKA YSAPRRPTATGDYDK 25.897  22.884
>sp|O14618|CCS_HUMAN Copper chaperone for superoxide dismutase OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=CCS PE=1 SV=1                 
267 S   AGC/PKA AGKGRKESAQPPAHL 25.541  22.884
>sp|O14828|SCAM3_HUMAN Secretory carrier-associated membrane protein 3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SCAMP3 PE=1 SV=3                  
32  S   AGC/PKA AVIQHRPSRQYATLD 24.52   22.884
76  S   AGC/PKA LQPSRKLSPTEPKNY 27.39   22.884
```

how can i import this in R into a dataframe like this:

```
A6NMZ2 25.507
O00501 23.138
O00501 25.897
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pattern in the data, names (Column1) are in rows on 2nd column that start with `">sp"` delimited by `"|"`, and numbers (Column2) are in following rows after `">sp"` rows in 5th column, something like this should work:

```
x <- readLines("myFile.txt")

do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(split(x, cumsum(grepl(">sp", x, fixed = TRUE))), function(i){
          cbind.data.frame(Col1 = unlist(strsplit(i[ 1 ], "|", fixed = TRUE))[ 2 ],
                           Col2 = read.table(text = i[ 2:length(i) ])[, 5])
        }))
#       Col1   Col2
# 1   A6NMZ2 25.507
# 2.1 O00501 23.138
# 2.2 O00501 25.897
# 3   O14618 25.541
# 4.1 O14828 24.520
# 4.2 O14828 27.390
```

**Note:** Bash/regex would be a better tool for this task.

Comment: i am getting this errror when i try your code: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 12 elements